# Unable to resolve 'ArquillianServletRunner not found error' for wildfly remote container

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to implement arquillian test for my class using the wildfly remote container.

I am a rookie in Java EE, so unable to figure out what am I doing wrong. I have added the dependencies to the pom.xml .

**Error Report**

```
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.326 sec <<< FAILURE!
create(com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository.BookRepositoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.031 sec  <<< ERROR!
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer.
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletUtil.determineBaseURI(ServletUtil.java:61)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletURIHandler.locateTestServlet(ServletURIHandler.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:75)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:128)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:139)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:15)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8.evaluate(Arquillian.java:332)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:204)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:350)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:215)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:285)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:166)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:350)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Tests in error:
create(com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository.BookRepositoryTest): ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer.

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

**POM.xml**

It contains the dependencies for arquillian junit, wildfly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.pluralsight.javaee-getting-started</groupId>
<artifactId>bookstore-back</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>bookstore-back</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**Test Class**

```
package com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class BookRepositoryTest {
@Deployment
public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
            .addClass(BookRepository.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
}

@org.junit.Test
public void create() {
}
}
```

**arquillian.xml**

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

<!-- Sets the protocol which is how Arquillian talks and executes the tests inside the container -->
<defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

<!-- Configuration to be used when the WidlFly remote profile is active -->
<container qualifier="widlfly-remote">
    <configuration>
        <property name="managementAddress">127.0.0.1</property>
        <property name="managementPort">9990</property>
        <property name="username">admin</property>
        <property name="password">admin</property>
    </configuration>
</container>

</arquillian>
```

Comment: Is WildFly 10 a requirement? You may be able to use a newer version of `wildfly-arquillian` as there were some bugs around this area.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins actually I am using wildfly-15.0.0.Final

Comment: You may be hitting https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFARQ-35 then. Can you try the version 2.1.1.Final?